# Using RectVisible on Windows Forms Control

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, gdi

I'm trying to figure out if a windows forms control is visible to the user or is obstructed from view by another control or form (tabbed view). I have tried GetUpdateRect trick but it only works if the window is  minimized.  I found the [RectVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but am not sure how to use it from  Windows Forms User control.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Only works if the window is minimized".  The solution with GetUpdateRect works:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
    public int Width { get { return this.Right - this.Left; } }
    public int Height { get { return this.Bottom - this.Top; } }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetUpdateRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect, bool bErase);

public static bool IsControlVisibleToUser(Control control)
{
    control.Invalidate();
    var bounds = control.Bounds;
    var rect = new Rect {Left=bounds.Left, Right = bounds.Right, Top = bounds.Top, Bottom = bounds.Bottom};
    return GetUpdateRect(control.Handle, ref rect, false);
}
```

Comment: I have two user controls that are hosted on different tab pages of a tab control. When i test them using your code they both say visible even though there is only one active tab at a time

Comment: @unclepaul84 I cannot duplicate your failure. You are calling Is...Visible twice - once for each user control variable?  When are you calling it?

Comment: I'm calling it from a timer thread every 10 seconds using control.Invoke